# Create object from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a small problem.

**I have such an array of objects:**

```
Array
[
  0: {
    name: "someName",
    value: "someValue"
  },
  1: {
    name: "someName",
    value: "someValue"
  }
  ...
]
```

**I would like to get:**

```
Object
{
  "someName": "someValue",
  "someName": "someValue",
  ...
}
```

**It is very easy to map... but I do not know how to properly assign this to an object**

```
myArray.map(element => console.log(element.name, element.value));
```

Comment: Use ```array#reduce```

Comment: Not exactly. This is the situation where the array has arrays.

Comment: Your `.map()` was just logging, and not actually mapping to a new array. If each `.map()` iteration returned a new object with a new key-value pair, you could then use the resulting array with `Object.assign`.

Comment: Like this: `var result = Object.assign({}, ...data.map(element => ({[element.name]: element.value})));`

Comment: Or this: `var result = Object.assign({}, ...data.map(({name, value}) => ({[name]: value})))`

Comment: Or use `.reduce()` like this: `var result = data.reduce((res, {name, value}) => Object.assign(res, {[name]: value}), {})`

Comment: llama, Thank you!!!